# Why isn't my CSS animation-timeline: view() working?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get my element to animate with `animation-timeline: view();` but, It just doesnt seem to be working. At all...

I got it to work before in a site of mine for a parallax effect [here](https://jos3ph1205.github.io/little-king/) and now it isn't working anymore no matter what i do!

Here's the code:

```
<div class="parallax">
  <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/grayscale-water-drop-Y6-GL40aPPs" alt="" />
</div>
```

```
.parallax {
   overflow: clip;
   height: 20vh;

   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

.parallax > img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
   animation: parallaxY linear;
   animation-timeline: view();
   animation-range: entry cover;
}

@keyframes parallaxY {
   from {
      translate: 0 -100px;
   }
   to {
      translate: 0 100px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked Browser compatibility of view()?

Comment: Yes, it's all supposed to work. I mean, it still works in my previous site as well.

Answer (score 2):

Right after I post a question, I crack my own problem. I'd already been fiddling around with this for two days!

Turns out the issue was a `overflow: hidden` property that I set on the parent of the `.parallax` element.

I comletely forgot that css animations dont work if the target element's parent has its overflow set to hidden.

I hope this helps other people with the same problem!

Comment: As an addition: It has been common practice in the past to add an `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `<body>` and `<html>` elements to prevent horizontal scrolling when elements would accidentally peek outside of their borders.

This now blocks `animation-timeline: view()`. And yes... even vertical scrolling when only `overflow-x` is set to hidden.